# Electrodynamics of inhomogeneous media

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, scattering, maxwell-equations, dielectric

I'm interested in electromagnetic scattering and for that purpose I would like to write out Maxwell's equations for space-dependent permittivity (and permeability).

Actually I only need them for dielectrics.

As writing out everything is quite lengthy I was wondering whether there's some good and genereal literature on this.

EDIT: This is about classical electromagnetism and the focus is that the medium in which the field propagates/evolves is inhomogeneous.

Comment: Welcome on physics.stackexchange. What kind of scattering do you mean? Nucleus-nucleus scattering, solid phase interactions or something else? Maybe someone understands exactly what you mean, but certainly not everyone. You also should formulate a specific problem/show what you already have.

Comment: Thank you! I mean classical electromagnetic scattering for dielectrics, i.e. time Evolution for the electromagnetic field incident on a dielectric substance described by ist permittivity.

Comment: Especially I'm interested in whether one could possibly obtain some modified wave equation or something else that's relatively easy to solve for highly symmetric media.