# A basic book (undergraduate level similar to Halliday and Resnick) about light scattering

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, resource-recommendations, scattering

In wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering
We read:  Originally, the term (Scattering)  was confined to light scattering (going back at least as far as Isaac Newton in the 17th century.

I am looking for a book about the basics of light scattering. Any suggestion?
I am looking for a more basic book in the undergraduate level similar to Halliday and Resnick.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454357/2451

Answer (score 0):

Nonlinear Optics by Robert Boyd gives a good introduction to Light scattering including Rayleigh, Brillouin, and Raman. It also discusses stimulated and spontaneous scattering processes. Chapters 8, 9, 10, some math mostly related to phase matching conditions. Not particularly rigorous but more than good enough to understand what is going on.

Fundamentals of Photonics by Saleh and Teich has a brief (and somewhat scattered) introduction of scattering but with very nice pictures! Spread out between multiple chapters, little to no proofs.

Classical Electrodynamics by the late John D. Jackson (RIP) presents a pretty mathematically thorough (at least for me) introduction, working from Maxwell’s equations.  Chapter 10 with much math.

If you are into Optics for the long term I would really recommend all of the above 3!

Comment: Thank you @Fredrik Sy. I am looking for a more basic book in the undergraduate level similar to Halliday and Resnick. I will edit my question to include this.

Comment: @Aria gotcha! I’m going through my optics textbook trying to find one, unfortunately the best undergrad optics textbook I know (Intro to Optics by Pedrotti^3) doesn’t have an introduction to scattering.

Comment: @Aria after going through everything I have the closest I can find to introductory scattering is Fundamentals of Photonics by Saleh, it is very readable even at the undergrad level but it is not a book on scattering in particular and can be quite expensive. While I think the book set (it has 2 volumes) is quite good it may not be worthwhile for you. Hopefully others will recommend something better.